# Connection unsuccessful in XMPP. Return null as host

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

Can anyone please suggest why gethost() returns null. How do I connect with my current openfire server which is configured locally.

```
XMPPConnection connection;
ConnectionConfiguration config;

config = new ConnectionConfiguration("FR4YW1S", 5222);
    connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
    try {
        connection.connect();

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Successfully Connected");
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("LOG_TAG", "Failed to connect to " + connection.getHost());
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Not Connected");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the host name to **ConnectionConfiguration("your_xmpp_host_name", 5222)** constructor on which your openfire is configured and not just any name. Like "jabber.org" or "www.example.com" or "myxmpp.example.com". You can also provide your server's IP(should be static) as your host name.

Comment: I have configured the server on my local system only and even if i use "127.0.0.1" then also it gives the same error. The current string is the server name:                                                                           Java Version:  1.7.0 Oracle Corporation -- Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
Appserver:  jetty/7.x.y-SNAPSHOT
Host Name:  FR4YW1S
OS / Hardware:  Windows XP / x86
Locale / Timezone:  en / India Standard Time (5 GMT)

Comment: It will never work as you are targetting localhost from android device, it will never gonna find that address. Here a thing you can do if you have any server with domain name then install openfire on it and link your domain to the openfire path and then give that path in your host name.

Comment: Can I use a web hosting account for this purpose? I have a domain and web hosting account on godaddy. Is that the correct way to do it?

Comment: yes you can use your web domain. just install openfire on your server and configure it.
Here see this guide  http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/install-guide.html

Comment: Thanks buddy!! I will try it soon on my server.